# Weakly continuous function but not strongly continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

It is known that, if a function $f$ from a planar domain $D$ to a Banach space $A$ is weakly analytic [i.e. $l(f)$ is analytic for every $l$ in $A^*$], then $f$ is strongly analytic [i.e. $\lim_{h \to 0} h^{-1}[f(z+h)-f(z)]$ exists in norm for every $z$ in $D$].

Now the question is, if above $f$ is assumed to be weakly continuous [i.e.$l(f)$ is continuous for every $l$ in $A^*$], then is it true that $f$ will be strongly continuous.[i.e. $\lim_{h \to 0} [f(z+h)-f(z)] = 0$ in norm for every $z$ in $D$.]

Comment: You mean continuous in the norm topology but not in the weak topology?

Comment: I mean continuous in weak topology but not in norm topology.

Comment: It is well known that weakly analytic function on a planar domain is strongly analytic.But what about continuous function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the clarified question with finite dimensional domain. Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional separable and reflexive Banach space. Its unit ball $B$ is weakly compact and metrizable. It is also convex.

So by  Hahn–Mazurkiewicz theorem  there exists a continuous function $f\colon [0,1]\to B$ that is onto $B$. This function is not norm continuous as $B$ is not norm compact.

Comment: can you give me some reference for the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem? Does not there exist any function in explicit form?

Comment: there is definitely no function in explicit form. Basically, one shows that the set $B$ is the image of the cantor set. try finding an explicit form for a path filling curve from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]^2$. Now try finding one for the unit ball of $L_2$. I'll add, the answer to your question is that weak continuity does not imply strong continuity even if the domain is finite dimensional; and we can find such an example for every metrizable domain in which we embed $[0,1]$ as a closed set.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Let $T_w$ denote the weak topology and let $T$ denote the norm topology. Then $\mathrm{id}: (X, T_w) \to (X, T)$ is not continuous but $\mathrm{id}: (X, T_w) \to (X, T_w)$ is.

Note that every map $f: X \to Y$ that is weakly continuous where weakly means $f: (X, T_w) \to Y$ is also strongly continuous, $f: (X, T) \to Y$, since the norm (or strong) topology contains more open sets than the weak topology (by definition).

Comment: Well in my actual question domain of the function was a planar domain with usual euclidean norm. If the range is again complex plane then we know for finite dimension Banach space weak topology  and strong topology are same.

Comment: @timon Such important information ought to be included in the body of your question.

Comment: Yes, to what Byron said. Thanks, Byron.

Comment: @timon Sure, $X$ has to be infinite dimensional. That's quite vital for the argument to be true. Sorry for not writing the most important thing. In any case: can you please make your question a bit clearer? Like: edit in all the information. Thanks!

Comment: sorry matt, it was my mistake that i forgot to include those information.Next time i will be careful.This time i am editing now.

Comment: @timon No problem : ) Could you point me to a definition of "planar domain"? I googled it but could not find a definition.

Comment: @matt planar domain means a open connected subset of the complex plane.

Comment: @timon Nice, thanks!